# What goes on at a meeting of a "teaching commision" in Switzerland?

Tags: teaching, switzerland

I'm an undergraduate student in Switzerland. Tomorrow, I am going to attend the teaching commission as a delegate. The teaching commission is responsible for quality control of the teaching and the improvement of the course offering and plan of studies.  I have the right to give some remarks, ask questions and vote.

I've never attended  one of these meetings before, so I am a little bit scared. What typically goes on at one of these meetings? What kind of questions are typically asked? What kind of remarks will be expected from the delegates?

Comment: @laura, could you please insert this explanation of what it is, and what the rules are? What actual power do the students have? Is it purely "advisory"? Or can the students "force" some changes? Who decides? Etc.?

Comment: @paulgarrett I think if Laura knew all that, she wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a difference in such situations, don't focus on individuals, especially poor instructors. Instead, focus on the challenges you have in learning that might be made easier if the system were somehow different. If you can suggest changes, all the better. But the design of the system is up to those who control it and information from folks like yourself can help them see where it could be improved. How to improve it is their task.

At the moment, with COVID disrupting everything, it is especially helpful for people to hear the effect of the change in delivery that students are experiencing and what is missing in the current environment. People are forced to use mechanisms at the moment that are suboptimal and might be improved with the appropriate feedback.